# writing my own version of List.filter in F#

Tags: f#

I'm attempting to rewrite List.filter manually
so far I have this:

```
let rec filter f = function
    |[] -> []
    |x::xs -> if f x = true then x @ filter f xs
              else filter f xs;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator `@` appends 2 lists so `x` in `if ... then ... else` expression is supposed to be of type `list`.
You probably meant to use list cons operator `::`. Also you don't need to compare the result of function `f` application to `true`.

```
let rec filter f = function
    |[] -> []
    |x::xs -> if f x then x :: filter f xs
              else filter f xs

[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9] |> filter (fun x -> x % 2 = 0)
```

> val it : int list = [2; 4; 6; 8]

Note: this function is not tail recursive so you'll get stack overflow exception with big lists.

Answer (score 6):

I'd add to the accepted answer that recognizing and applying functional patterns may be as important as mastery of recursion and pattern matching. And probably the first of such patterns is [folding](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/98075.pdf).

Implementing your task with folding takes a terse:

```
let filter p ls = List.foldBack (fun l acc -> if p l then l::acc else acc) ls []
```

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty understanding your implementation, could you maybe comment on it? It might be a lack of properly understanding `list.foldback`, but the part after `->` boggles my mind a little.

Comment: @Left4Cookies: `List.foldback` allows you building filtered list  with `::` preserving original ordering of elements; using `List.fold` instead would require applying `List.rev` to the filtered list in order to restore the original ordering. As to `if p l then l::acc else acc` - no magic here: if predicate `p` is `true` for the current element `l`, then `cons` `l` to the accumulator `acc`, otherwise just pass thru `acc`. Running a quick and dirty sample may help understanding.